# Не работает Uglify в Webpack3.1

Tags: webpack, минификация

Здравствуйте.
Не работает UglifyJS в webpack3.1, притом никаких ошибок или предупреждений нет, при смене параметра sourceMap: true тоже ноль реакции.
использую стандартно:

```
const     UglifyJSPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
new UglifyJSPlugin({
    sourceMap: true,
    test: /\.js($|\?)/i,
    exclude: /\/node_modules/,
    include: /\/dist/
});
devtool: 'source-map'
```

в данной конфигурации я пробую собирать Angular5

typescript работает, scss тоже, а вот минификатор как-будто просто отсутствует и ни на что не реагирует. 
в чём может быть "загвоздка"?

Answer (score 0):

не знаю в чем ошибка но у меня вот так работает

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
module.exports = function(){
  return{
    plugins:[
      new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
        sourceMap: true,
        compress: {
          warnings:false,
        },
        output:{
          comments: false,
        }
      })
    ]
  }
};
```